# How to search GitHub for GitHub Actions repos?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-search

**GitHub's official** Actions are available in the repositories here: https://github.com/actions

**Third party** Actions can be found somewhat haphazardly (by browsing repositories and scanning their readmes). Example: https://github.com/docker/build-push-action

To avoid the haphazard nature of browsing, I'd like to use GitHub's search box but limit results to only repositories that are GitHub Actions - is there a way to search GitHub exclusively for repositories that are GitHub Actions? (that is, repos that can be the value provided to the `uses` instruction in a `workflow.yml` file)

Comment: You may search for `action.yml` or `action.yaml` file at the root of the repos to identify them as GitHub action. Also, you may go to https://github.com/marketplace and simply search for Actions there. See [Publishing actions in GitHub Marketplace](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/publishing-actions-in-github-marketplace) for more details.